# Integral Bessel recurrence relation

Tags: special-functions

I want to show that $\int x^vJ_{v-1}(x)dx = x^vJ_v(x) + C$.

Now I know the recurrence relations of the Bessel equation/function and the one I need to use is $x^vJ_v(x) = x^vJ_{v-1}(x)$

I'm just thinking to set v as a constant and just integrate with respect to x but the $J_v(x)$ is confusing me...I don't see how that will turn out to be $J_{v-1}(x)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relation to use is
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx} \left[ x^{\nu} J_{\nu}(x) \right] = x^{\nu} J_{\nu-1}(x).
\end{align}
Integrating both sides with respect to $x$ yields
\begin{align}
\int \frac{d}{dx} \left[ x^{\nu} J_{\nu}(x) \right] \ dx &= \int x^{\nu} J_{\nu-1}(x) \ dx
\end{align}
or
\begin{align}
\int x^{\nu} J_{\nu-1}(x) = x^{\nu} J_{\nu}(x) + \mbox{ constant }.
\end{align}
which provides the desired result.

Comment: hmm so is this correct? $\frac{d}{dx} \left[ x^{\nu} J_{\nu}(x) \right] = \int x^vJ_{v-1}(x)dx$
and $x^vJ_{v-1}(x) = \int x^vJ_{v-1}(x) = x^{\nu} J_{\nu}(x) +C$?

Comment: Using $\int \frac{d}{dx} f(x) dx = f(x)$ leads to the desired result. A line has been added to make clear the integration of both sides as stated.